# Cannot Login to the Application After Uploading to Server in Code Igniter

Tags: session, authentication, codeigniter-3

I made an application that prompt the user to log in. When I ran the application in my laptop on localhost, the application is fine, nothing wrong. However, once the application is uploaded to the server, I couldn't login. After I entered the username and password and clicked the login button, the application redirected me to the login page. I wonder what went wrong?

Comment: Please check the php version on the server, the session is not work for php 7, needs to refer this thread https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-68765.html

Comment: @Tarunmodi The server is using PHP 5.6.37 and the session is working just fine as I checked the folder where the session is written, the session file does exist.

Comment: can you add your code?

Comment: Always check error_log to see if anything wierd is happening.